# blob with conversion to 8bit cp1251 or cp1252

Tags: javascript, encoding, utf-8, cp1252, cp1251

I need a solution with encoding utf to 8-bit cp1251 or cp1252 using blob

I managed to change the 
https://github.com/b4stien/js-csv-encoding including windows 1251, but there are insoluble problems:

Unfortunately noscript does not allow loading external javascript on a page with scripts turned off via it.

Therefore, it is impossible to use js-csv-encoding in the bookmarker, as well as to load jquery! Disabling noscript, especially after meltdown and specter is simply not secure.

Therefore, only the version of a small script written in native javascript is left.
If you find an alternative way to run jquery with noscript off, then finding a solution will be easier although I doubt it's possible.

A good solution would be 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-1251 or https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-1252
However, it does not succeed to transcode two-byte text into a single-byte text through these scripts. For example:

```
<script src="windows-1251.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function download(text, name, type) {
var a = document.getElementById("a");
var file = new Blob([text], {type: type});
a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
a.download = name;
</script>
```

There have been many attempts to use windows1251, for example these:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function exportToCsv() {
window.open(windows1251.encode('data:text/csv;charset=windows-1251,' +'текст'));
}
var button = document.getElementById('b');
button.addEventListener('click', exportToCsv);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function exportToCsv() {window.open('data:text/csv;charset=windows-1251,' +windows1251.encode('текст'));}

var button = document.getElementById('b');
button.addEventListener('click', exportToCsv);
</script>
```

Using encode or decode from windows-1251 does not translate the script into a 8-bit format. In js-csv-encoding, csvContentEncoded is used for transcoding:

Attempts to use something like that have failed. Perhaps you need some kind of hack, just put windows-1251 is not enough,
since js stores in utf8, then most likely you need to add the conversion to 1251 at the very end. Part of the code: js-csv-encoding.

```
var csvContent = 'текст',
textEncoder = new CustomTextEncoder('windows-1251', {NONSTANDARD_allowLegacyEncoding: true}),
fileName = 'some-data.csv';
var a = document.getElementById('download-csv');
a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
var csvContentEncoded = textEncoder.encode([csvContent]);
var blob = new Blob([csvContentEncoded], {type: 'text/csv;charset=windows-1251;'});
saveAs(blob, fileName);
e.preventDefault();
});
```

I also tried to use conversions using charcode, saving not to the server but to the computer, so using urlencode .. is not the right solution, because in this case I have to encode the text into the readable one.

Of course, it's hard to find a solution of no more than 4000-5000 characters for a bookmarklet, and my knowledge is not enough.
If there is a solution with the help of other scripts, for example, recoding by the value table, this can also be a solution.

Comment: Why do you need this in a bookmarklet? Why do you need to run this bookmarklet that often on a site where you cannot disable noscript?

Comment: First, now any site is unsafe. The recent specter and meltdown vulnerabilities can give the chance to read the memory even with the js script, not to mention the browser exploit
A bookmarklet is required for many solutions, for example, saving text from a site to a regular txt.

Comment: I would guess that you still can configure noscript to trust specific scripts/sites that you trust enough to use them regularly (or have verified yourself not to contain a spectre exploit).

Comment: However, the chance of using the attack remains, especially because of the different ways of injecting the script into any possible site, in addition most sites have external scripts that can be changed. There are a lot of ways to attack.
Using such bookmarklets for example, such that you can see the hidden elements of the site (visible: false ...) or load content, other such bookmarklets allow you to perform the necessary operations with the scripts turned off,
and therefore without fear of using miners, advertising ..

Answer (score 1):

I spent the half of the day trying to save an xml file with Cyrillic symbols in windows-1251 encoding. Turned out it's pretty easy - you just need to create an appropriate byte array. See the example below ([The full repo with this example](https://github.com/andrewdonskikh/save-as-windows-1251)):

```js
import iconv from 'pika-iconv-lite';
import saveAs from 'save-as';

const byteArrayWin1251 = iconv.encode(
  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
  <note>
    <to>Михаил</to>
    <from>Андрей</from>
    <heading>Reminder</heading>
    <body>Вот такая вот xml! И сохранюсь я как win-1251</body>
  </note>`,
  'win1251'
);
const blob = new Blob([byteArrayWin1251], { type: 'application/xml;charset=windows-1251' })
saveAs(blob, 'myxml.xml');
```