# Cannot change csv file charset to windows-1251

Tags: javascript, character-encoding

I try to create a button that would download a csv file. I have to make the file using windows-1251 charset.
But no matter what I do the file ended up in utf-8. Right now I'm trying something like:

```
async createCsv(result) {
    const arrData = result.data
    const aliases = result.aliases
    
    let csvContent = [
        Object.keys(arrData[0]).map(item => aliases[item]).join(";"),
        ...arrData.map(item => Object.values(item).join(";"))
    ]
    .join("\n")
    .replace(/(^\[)|(\]$)/gm, "");
    
    const data = new Blob([csvContent], {
        type: "text/csv;charset=windows-1251;"
    });
    
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", URL.createObjectURL(data));
    link.setAttribute("download", (new Date).toLocaleString() + ".csv");
    link.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

And the file is in utf-8.
Is there a way to change the charset?

Comment: Do you **really** need Windows-1251? It is a Microsoft-specific variant of an obsolete ISO standard that has been superseded by UTF-8. Updating the system that expects such an outdated encoding would probably be a better solution to this problem.

Comment: @Quentin, you can't change the systems that are out of your control.

Answer (score 0):

looking for the same last day.
that's the answer that really works
[blob with conversion to 8bit cp1251 or cp1252](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48138057/blob-with-conversion-to-8bit-cp1251-or-cp1252)

in my project ends up with the following

```
import * as iconv from 'iconv-lite'
```

```
let outdata = this.bankf.getOutputFile();
const encoded = iconv.encode (outdata,'win1251');

var file = new Blob ([encoded], {type: 'text/plain;charset=windows-1251'});
var link = document.createElement("a");
var url = URL.createObjectURL(file);
link.setAttribute("href", url);
link.setAttribute("download", "filename.txt");
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
setTimeout(function() {document.body.removeChild(link); window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url); }, 0);
```

still looking for other solution as iconv brings around 400kb code , but for now. at least it works